# Multiple bool var check inside condition

Tags: javascript, variables, boolean

Is this ok way to check if all 4 variables have same value instead of checking each individually?

```
if (bodovi >= min_bodovi && (Q15,Q16,Q17,Q18) == true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify that to:

```
if (bodovi >= min_bodovi && Q15 && Q16 && Q17 && Q18)
```

Given that these are boolean variables, their value being TRUE is sufficient for javascript to evaluate each as TRUE. If one of them id false, e.g. `Q15 = false`, then it will fail

Comment: That's great, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the green tick to the left of this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Will validate only the last variable, here if Q18 is true then the condition will just pass even if Q15,Q16,Q17 are false or any one of them false.

```
(Q15,Q16,Q17,Q18) == true
```

You can use (Q15 && Q16 && Q17 && Q18)